# Image Magick not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rmagick

I've installed RMagick, specified the gem in my gemile, committed chanages.  Pushed to Heroku, Heroku shows it was installed in log, but when I attempt to upload a picture I get this notice:

Image Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.

Help a new hobbyist out here!

Rails 4.1.8
Ruby 2.1.5
Heroku Cedar

`gem 'rmagick'` in gemfile

Comment: what uploader gem are you using?  Paperclip?  Carrierwave?  Also, where are you uploading the files too (fyi, you can't upload to Heroku).

Comment: I'm using Paperclip.  I've already added the code to redirect images to AWS.  Strange that ImageMagick isn't showing up on Heroku, I was under the understanding it was preloaded everywhere except bamboo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working,i had totally the same problem 
just add Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'Path to your ImagineMagick'

In all your environments...and the most important!!
add it to your actual environment.rb file it is in config folder mine looks like this

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.initialize!
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\ImageMagicks'
```

[image: Click To see the image]

and this is my Production.rb
[image: Production.rb]

Now it should work.